# How can you run powershell from Java?

Tags: java, powershell, processbuilder

I'm trying to use Process and ProcessBuilder to execute a ps1 file through powershell. I'm struggling with the entire thing and cant even get the powershell.exe to run. Ive tried :

```
 // Wont Run

 // Defined specific path for powershell - trying to simply run the exe file
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"); 
 Process p = pb.start();
```

I've look at [Running Powershell from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623369/running-powershell-from-java) and [Run a powershell on a remote machine using JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152360/run-a-powershell-on-a-remote-machine-using-java) trying to implement methods from these examples but I dont understand why mine wont even run an instance of powershell.

I do eventually want to incorporate running ps1 files through here but I need to walk before I can run.

Also, I have checked Task Manager and it **IS** running as a process.

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to why this wont even run ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If PowerShell is showing up in Task Manager, then it sounds like you have successfully launched it. Try doing something like this and see what happens: `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -Command \"New-Item c:\imadethis.txt -type file\"");`

Comment: I managed to successfully launch it by complete fluke, I opted to use process builder, and the actual path of the ps1 file needed to be in quotations, which mine wasn't. I also used 'p.getOutputStream().close();' as the problem seemed to be that powershell first reads all input from it's input stream before continuing. I wanted to run it as a background process so it wasnt essential that powershell was displayed. Tried your solution which also worked so great for anyone else looking at this !